# Fullcalendar - highlighting a day based on event selection

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar you can select an event (which triggers) the eventClick function/callback.  What I would like to do is highlight the day of the event when the event is clicked (in month view).

For example, if the event is on October 30 and I select the event I would like the background color of the day to be highlighted.   This is very similar to how fullcalendar handles "today" where it highlights today in a yellowish color.

I can't seem to figure out how to tie the fc-event class or the event object itself to the actual day div in the calendar.  My October 30th event appears within the following div (which is the October 30 box):

```
<div class="fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-day35 fc-first">
```

How can I find this div (so that I can highlight it) based on the event object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry this is a rough solution, mostly from memory, as I'm not set up with any dev tools at this computer.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for!

```
//create fullCalendar:
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    /* options */

    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent){
        //use the passed-in javascript event to get a jQuery-wrapped reference
        //to the DOM element we clicked on.
        //i can never remember if this is .target, .currentTarget, or .originalTarget
        //... jquery has spoiled me
        var $clickedEvent = $(jsEvent.target);

        //tell the "selectionManager" to find the day this event belongs to,
        //and add the "selected" css class to it
        selectionManager.select($clickedEvent);
    }
});

//define an object that handles the adding-removing of the 'selectedDay' css class
var selectionManager = (function(){
    //i like making private variables :-)
    var $curSelectedDay = null

    //define a "select" method for switching 'selected' state
    return {
        select: function($newEvent) {
            if ($curSelectedDay){
                //if we already had a day chosen, let's get rid of its CSS 'selectedDay' class
                $curSelectedDay.removeClass("selectedDay");
            }
            //find the parent div that has a class matching the pattern 'fc-day', and add the "selectedDay" class to it
            $curSelectedDay = $thisEvent.closest('div[class~="fc-day"]').addClass("selectedDay");
        }       
    };
})();
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted but you pointed me in the right direction with your code.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use the [select method](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/) in full calendar.

For example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', date);
```

Where `date` comes from `event.start`:

```
eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {
    //pass event.start to select method
}
```

Comment: Great solution, **as long as the event is only one day long**.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly simpler solution that worked for me:

```
$(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
$(jsEvent.currentTarget).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
```

...that goes inside of your click handler, like:

```
$('#eventCalendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $(jsEvent.currentTarget).addClass("fc-state-highlight");

    }
});
```

Note that this is using the `dayClick` handler instead of the `eventClick` handler.  I don't see why it should not work with `eventClick` as well, but I have not tested that yet.

**Edit:**

Using a comparable approach for the `eventClick` handler proved to be more complicated than I thought it would be.  The problem is that, in terms of DOM hierarchy, there is no parent/child relationship between the containing `td` element for a 'day' and the containing `div` elements for the events that are shows as occurring on that day.

So I had to write a function to lookup the correct `td` element for a given date.  I ended up with something like:

```
function findContainerForDate(date) {
    var firstDayFound = false;
    var lastDayFound = false;
    var calDate = $('#eventCalendar').fullCalendar('getDate');

    var allDates = $('td[class*="fc-day"]')
    for (var index = 0; index < allDates.length; index++) {
        var container = allDates[index];
        var month = calDate.getMonth();
        var dayNumber = $(container).find(".fc-day-number").html();
        if (dayNumber == 1 && ! firstDayFound) {
            firstDayFound = true;
        }
        else if (dayNumber == 1) {
            lastDayFound = true;
        }

        if (! firstDayFound) {
            month--;
        }
        if (lastDayFound) {
            month++;
        }

        if (month == date.getMonth() && dayNumber == date.getDate()) {
            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

...and then I could implement `eventClick` like this:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var selectedContainer = findContainerForDate(calEvent.start);

    $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
    $(selectedContainer).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {          
        // like that
        var dateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');

        // or that
        var cell = view.dateToCell(event.start);
        view.element.find('tr:eq(' + (cell.row + 1) + ') td:eq(' + cell.col + ')').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
    }
```

Is there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

My take on aroth's finder function

```js
     // based on the given event date return the full calendar day jquery object (<td ...>)
     // matching day and month
     //
     // assumptions:
     //  - the event date is if for the same year as the current viewable month
     //  - the fc-day* TD's are in chronological order
     //  - the fc-day* TD's not for the current month have a class of fc-other-month
     //
    findFullCalendarDayForClickedEvent : function( eventDate ) {

        var foundDay;

        var $theCalendar = $( '#myCalendar' );

        var currentDate = $theCalendar.fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
        var fullCalendarDayContainers = $theCalendar.find( 'td[class*="fc-day"]' );

        for( var i = 0; i < fullCalendarDayContainers.length; i++ ) {

            var $currentContainer = $( fullCalendarDayContainers[ i ] );

            var dayNumber = $currentContainer.find( '.fc-day-number' ).html();

            // first find the matching day
            if ( eventDate.getDate() == dayNumber ) {

                // now month check, if our current container has fc-other-month
                // then the event month and the current month needs to mismatch,
                // otherwise container is missing fc-other-month then the event
                // month and current month need to match
                if( $currentContainer.hasClass( 'fc-other-month' ) ) {

                    if( eventDate.getMonth() != currentDate.getMonth() ) {
                        foundDay = $currentContainer;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ( eventDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth() ) {
                        foundDay = $currentContainer;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return foundDay;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fitz Agard's answer for the existence of fullcalendar *select* method, here's a version that works even for multiple days events.

Basically it tries to find the day the mouse click coordinates are within, then it passes its date to the fullcalendar *select* method.

```
function findClickedDay(e) {
 var days = $('#calendar .fc-day');
  for(var i = 0 ; i < days.length ; i++) {
      var day = $(days[i]);
      var mouseX = e.pageX;
      var mouseY = e.pageY;
      var offset = day.offset();
      var width  = day.width();
      var height = day.height();

      if (    mouseX > offset.left && mouseX < offset.left+width 
           && mouseY > offset.top  && mouseY < offset.top+height )
         return day;
  }
}

function myDayClick(date) { ... } // Optional

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date) { myDayClick(date); }, // Optional
  eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    clickedDay = findClickedDay(jsEvent);
    var date = new Date(clickedDay.data('date'));
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', date);
    myDayClick(date); // Optional
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I just realized fullCalendar *select* method does not trigger the *dayClick* callback. So if you have set a *dayClick* callback you must wrap it in a function (called *myDayClick* here) and call it in the *eventClick* callback. If you don't have a *dayClick* callback then you can remove the *Optional* parts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I've found that this works quite nicely, similar to kayz1's solution...

```
            $("[data-date='" + $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(calEvent.start)) + "']").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

So many answers. Little investigations give me more clear code: fullcalendar v2.1.1

```
 onDayClick = function( date, jsEvent, view ){
    var cell = view.dateToCell(date);
    var el = view.dayGrid.getCellDayEl(cell);
    var $clickedEvent = $(el);
    $clickedEvent.addClass("SelectedDay");
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you upgrade to fullcalendar v2 or greater it is very simple:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Here is the link for [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/).

Comment: Look at the OP's question: What I would like to do is highlight the DAY of the event when the event is clicked.  Your answer highlights the EVENT, not the DAY